# iOS - constraints and verify for traits

Tags: swift, autolayout, storyboard, constraints

So i am trying to do 2 types of constraints.
First for portrait and the second for landscape , yet i dont succeed.
This is what i ddid for the portrait :
[image: portrait]

This is the landscape:
[image: landscape]

yat the this is what i get in the simulator:

portrait: 
[image]

landscape:
[image]

As you can see , in the landscape i dont see the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using 3 different types of constrains :

**Compact Regular Portrait** on all phones

**Regular Compact in Landscape** for iPhone XS Max, iPhone XR and iPhone Plus phones 6+,7+,8+

**Compact Compact in Landscape** for iPhone X, iPhone 4s, iPhoneSE and iPhone 6,7,8

[image]
[image]

Try to add another 4 constrains of your 8 and it might work

[image]

Comment: i have 8
4 for the portrait and 4 for the landscape
the portraits are regular compact and the landscape are compact and compact.
you can see it in the left board , the constraints the are white light are the landscape and vis versa

Comment: it looks like it works in all simulators besides the X